# Ways to make variable name aliases

Tags: c++

I write some algorithms which take iterators as parameters. I want names of these iterators to reflect for users the fact that they denote a range so I name them like this:

```cpp
template < typename T >
void foo( T begin_i, T end_i ) {
    // ...
}
```

I also want to use these parameters in my code but in the context of implementation names `begin_i` and `end_i` don't reflect their purpose so I need name aliases for them. And that's what references are for, right?

```cpp
template < typename T >
void foo( T begin_i, T end_i ) {
    T& context_dependent_name1 = begin_i;
    T& context_dependent_name2 = end_i;
    // Code using aliases    
}
```

This works for me but it would be nice to hide initial names `begin_i`, `end_i`.
My questions are:

1. Is this a proper use of references? Are there any drawbacks ( other than couple of unused names in the scope)?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this?
3. Is there a way to hide initial names?

Comment: Why would the names you give to the user not be what you wan't to use in the function?  begin and end are very good names to denote a range.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a case where the parameter names don't make sense for the use in the implementation but you'd want to use a reference rather than a copy by value. Can you give an example?

Comment: @mattnewport I did an implementation of Introsort and as a part of it there was `partition( T begin_i, T end_i )` function. But inside the function I didn't need these iterators to always denote the whole sequence so I made alias `pivot` for the `end_i`(and decreased it by 1) and `right_part_begin` for `begin_i` and used them instead. I agree that it may be a design flaw rather than actual need though.

Comment: @DmitryKuznetsov In that case I think you should be using a new local variable and not a reference to `end_i` - if the name 'end' is not appropriate (because it's not actually referring to the end) then you don't want to be changing the value of `end_i` as a side effect of modifications to your new more appropriately named variable.

Comment: I sometimes make my parameters const and use new local variables with more suitable names in this situation, e.g. in the very common case of incrementing from `begin_i` to `end_i` (or `first` to `last` as I usually name them) I often prefer to make the parameters const and update a local iterator called `current`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative is to use one name in declaration, and an other in definition:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T begin_i, T end_i);
```

Later, or in .inl for example

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T context_dependent_name1, T context_dependent_name2) {
    // Implementation
}
```

It may produce warning for some documentation tools for the argument name mismatch though.

Answer (score 3):

1. Is this a proper use of references?

Yes.

2. Are there any drawbacks ( other than couple of unused names in the scope)?

No.

3. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Don't do it. It's pointless.

4. Is there a way to hide initial names?

No.